# How do i insert or attached .sql file into my Excel.xls file?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007

I'm making project documentation though I want to attach many sql files with columns
in excel file.

I tried like `Insert Object` > `Create File`

but it is not attaching file nor able to link that file

instead of link that file I would like to attachment in excel itself ,

so that using only one Excel.xls file i will have all other attachment files with me

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand what you need

Comment: Are you trying to get Excel to run several SQL queries and return the results to different worksheets (tabs)?

Comment: No I just want to attach that .sql file or you can say want to insert into excel as we attach or insert mail files in excel using `insert > object` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a .SQL file standard.

When you see such files they *generally* consist of a series of commands in some vendor-specific variant of the SQL language.  These commands can be fed into the vendor's SQL database product; the database engine will process them and update the database appropriately.

You look in the file to see if that's what you have, or whether you have some other (possibly binary) file that someone chose to apply a .sql extension to (some people do this with single-file SQLite databases, for example).

Because SQL varies from vendor to vendor, you may or may not be able to apply a file of SQL commands produced from one vendor's product to another vendor's database.

Excel does not understand the SQL language, so you will not be able to use a file of SQL commands to produce data in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: ok I just want to attach that file like we attach any mail in excel ?